# Main Resource name in new Activity : Android Studio 1.5.1

Tags: android, android-studio

When I create a new Blank Activity in Android Studio, I don't see the "Main resource name" text box in "Customize the Activity" screen. Attaching the screenshot for reference. Any idea why this happens?

[image: new Activity]

Edit:

Adding a screenshot of what I'm expecting.

[image]

Comment: what you mean by main resource??

Comment: Menu Resource is provided only for the first time when project is being created. But, does that matter ? This way, it just won't have 5-6 lines of code for inflating menu. Coding it manually will take hardly a minute or two.